# Assocating BDD Scenarios with results of Silverlight Tests

Tags: silverlight, cucumber, bdd, fitnesse

I work with a team that uses Behaviour Driven Development(BDD) to deliver our applications. We have started delivering Silverlight applications.

I would like to associate the agreed **BDD Scenarios written in plain text** to the results of the automated tests for our silverlight application.  So when a scenario is met in the application there is a simple report showing this mapped to the original text.  This is so our stakeholders (aka product owner) can quickly gain feedback on what acceptance criteria have been tested and delivered.

Previously I have used [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) and [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) along with xUnit/rSpec to help communication between the the product owner and the developers when using BDD to deliver web applications.

My problem is I do not see an easy way of plugging the Silverlight test framework results and the BDD scenario text using one of these reporting tools.

**My Question:** Has anyone delivering these kind of "reports" in a BDD project using Silverlight?  If so how did you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [Silverlight Test Framework](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) that ships in the Silverlight Toolkit, you unfortunately won't find any trivial extensibility points to report this kind of information back today.

Answer (score 2):

[SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org) is an open-source project to do BDD with .NET. From version 3.1.2 it also supports Silverlight. You can check the sample at: http://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/BowlingKata/BowlingKata-Silverlight-MsTest/

SpecFlow is using a plain text definition format (Gherkin - same format as cucumber), and it generates unit tests from it (in case of Silverlight, MsTest is supported).

You can also check the wiki about the SpecFlow Silvelight integration: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/silverlight-support